# The multi-part identifier columnName could not be bound

Tags: t-sql

I know this question has been posted several times, but after 1 hour on google I still can't get this to work

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.Year DESC, x.Month) AS ID,  
    x.*,
    Finance.fGetRates(x.XTimeStamp)
FROM 
    (  SELECT   Client,
                Month(TimeStamp) As Month,
                Year(TimeStamp) As Year,
                Day(TimeStamp) As Day,
                (dateadd(yy,(Year(TimeStamp)-1900),0)
               + dateadd(mm,Month(TimeStamp)-1,0) 
               + Day(TimeStamp)-1) AS XTimeStamp,
               Sum(KwTop) As KwTop,
               Sum(KwHeap) as KwHeap,
               Sum(KwLow) As KwLow  
      FROM Ori.vEnergyUnion  
      GROUP BY Year(TimeStamp), Month(TimeStamp),Day(TimeStamp), Client 
    ) x

LEFT OUTER JOIN Finance.fGetRates(x.XTimeStamp) Fr  
    ON Fr.ValidFrom = x.XTimeStamp 
ORDER BY Fr
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   The multi-part identifier
>   "x.XTimeStamp" could not be bound.

Any help would be appriciated, Thanks.

Comment: From the line number, which mention of `x.XTimeStamp` is the error message referring to?

Comment: I think it is "INNER JOIN Finance.fGetRates(x.XTimeStamp) Fr" as I get this guy marked if I double click the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters to functions across a `JOIN`.

Use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.Year DESC, x.Month) AS ID,  
        x.*,
        fr.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  Client,
                Month(TimeStamp) As Month,
                Year(TimeStamp) As Year,
                Day(TimeStamp) As Day,
                (dateadd(yy,(Year(TimeStamp)-1900),0)
                + dateadd(mm,Month(TimeStamp)-1,0) 
                + Day(TimeStamp)-1) AS XTimeStamp,
                Sum(KwTop) As KwTop,
                Sum(KwHeap) as KwHeap,
                Sum(KwLow) As KwLow  
       FROM     Ori.vEnergyUnion  
       GROUP BY
                Year(TimeStamp), Month(TimeStamp),Day(TimeStamp), Client 
       ) x
OUTER APPLY
       (
       SELECT  *
       FROM    Finance.fGetRates(x.XTimeStamp) Fr  
       WHERE   fr.ValidFrom = x.XTimeStamp 
       ) fr
```